# Using a Rolling Function in Pandas based on Date and a Categorical Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im currently working on a dataset where I am using the rolling function in pandas to
create features.

The functions rely on three columns a DaysLate numeric column from which the mean is calculated from, an Invoice Date column from which the date is derived from and a customerID column which denotes the customer of a row.

Im trying to get a rolling mean of the DaysLate for the last 30 days limited to invoices raised to a specific customerID.

The following two functions are working.

1. Mean of DaysLate for the last five invoices raised for the row's customer

```
df["CustomerDaysLate_lastfiveinvoices"] = df.groupby("customerID").rolling(window = 5,min_periods = 1).\
                              DaysLate.mean().reset_index().set_index("level_1").\
                              sort_index()["DaysLate"]
```

2. Mean of DaysLate for all invoices raised in the last 30 days

```
df = df.sort_values('InvoiceDate')
df["GlobalDaysLate_30days"] = df.rolling(window = '30d', on = "InvoiceDate").DaysLate.mean()
```

Just cant seem to find the code get the mean of the last 30 days by CustomerID. Any help on above is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the date column as index then sort to ensure ascending order then group the sorted dataframe by customer id and for each group calculate 30d rolling mean.

```
mean_30d = (
    df
    .set_index('InnvoiceDate') # !important
    .sort_index()
    .groupby('customerID')
    .rolling('30d')['DaysLate'].mean()
    .reset_index(name='GlobalDaysLate_30days')
)

# merge the rolling mean back to original dataframe
result = df.merge(mean_30d)
```